# Rmarkdown Error Quitting Error in UseMethod("select_") : no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "function

Tags: r, select, r-markdown, tidyverse

I got an error in RMarkdown.

```
Quitting from lines 23-54 (Report_Preliminary.Rmd) 
Error in UseMethod("select_") : 
  no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "function"
Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> select.default -> select_
Execution halted
```

This is my code I am trying to run

```
data_select <- data %>%
  dplyr::select(ID, Age, Gender, Location, Country, Chills, Cough, Diarrhoea, Fatigue, Headcahe, 'Healthcare Worker', 'How Unwell',
              'Long Standing Health Issues', 'Loss of smell and taste', 'Muscle Ache', 'Nasal Congestion', 'Nausea and Vomiting', 
              'Number Of Days Symptoms Showing',
              'Pregnant', 'Self Diagnosis', 'Shortness of Breath', 'Sore Throat','Reason For Helping', 'Sputum', 'Temperature') %>%
  dplyr::rename( id = ID,
                 age = Age,
                 gender = Gender,
                 location =  Location,
                 country = Country,
                 chills = Chills,
                 diarrhoea = Diarrhoea,
                 fatigue = Fatigue,
                 headache = Headcahe,
                 healthcare_worker = 'Healthcare Worker',
                 how_unwell = 'How Unwell',
                 long_standing_health = 'Long Standing Health Issues',
                 loss_smell_taste = 'Loss of smell and taste',
                 muscle_ache = 'Muscle Ache',
                 nasal_congestion = 'Nasal Congestion',
                 nausea_vomiting = 'Nausea and Vomiting',
                 no_days_symptoms_show = 'Number Of Days Symptoms Showing',
                 pregnant =  'Pregnant',
                 shortness_breath = 'Shortness of Breath',
                 sore_throat = 'Sore Throat',
                 sputum = 'Sputum',
                 temperature = 'Temperature',
                 self_diagnosis = 'Self Diagnosis',
                 tested_or_not = 'Reason For Helping')
```

Yet when I run each chunk in Rmarkdown I have no problem at all. I get the output needed. 
Has someone else had any issues around this?

Comment: It is hard to help you without a minimum reproducible piece of code, can you provide it ?

Comment: Jrm_FRL I can but what exactly ? Since I thought that will be enough? Are you referring to the whole script?

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data!

Comment: I am very sorry, I cannot as this is confidential work ... All I can say is that it is rather an Rmarkdown problem as the functions in my chunks work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by saving the data_select, with all the changes needed, into a folder and brought it in with read_csv.